# Date problems inserting data using stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table in my SQL Server database with a field DateAdded. I only want the date and time as the format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss so I have the smalldatetime data type selected for this field. I'm now creating a stored procedure to insert data into this table. Amongst other fields - not relevant to question - is the DateAdded as this is a non NULLABLE field.
My procedure is as follows:

```
alter procedure dbo.spAddStuffExample_Insert
@Name varchar(100),
@EmailAddress varchar(100),
@ContactNumber varchar(100),
@AdditionalInformation varchar(3000) = NULL,
@DateAdded smalldatetime = GetDate
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    insert into dbo.TableName (Name, EmailAddress, ContactNumber,AdditionalInformation , DateAdded)
    values(@Name, @EmailAddress, @ContactNumber,@AdditionalInformation, @DateAdded)
end
```

The wrong date is added to the record. DateAdded is 1900-01-01 00:00:00. I don't care about the format but it certainly isn't the 1900s.

Comment: in the table creation script you need to specify DateAdded SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(). After that you do not need to provide value for this column. It will be defined automatically

Comment: Note that DateAdded is a _column_, not a field. (And a date value has a year field, a month field etc.)

Comment: Fyi, `GetDate` is a function it requires `()` and you cannot use this as a parameter default value.

Comment: Welcome to a great T-SQL gotcha! `@DateAdded smalldatetime = GetDate` does not do what you think it does -- it attempts to assign the *string* `GetDate` (which is allowed unquoted for default parameter values) to your `smalldatetime` parameter. Of course this conversion would fail at runtime (but only if you leave out the parameter). Use `NULL` instead and `ISNULL(@DateAdded, GETDATE())` (or, as others have suggested, a default constraint). Note that using `GETDATE()` (with parentheses) as the initialization value is not allowed -- those values must be literals.

Comment: Obligatory warning that SQL Server 2008 ran *completely* out of support way back in 2019; you **need** to get your upgrade path finalised and implemented. Using such a product so long after it ran out of support is a significant vulnerability.

Comment: The second gotcha, of course, is that `''` converts to `1900-01-01` as a date -- allowing the empty string to convert to non-`NULL` defaults rather than producing an error is a dubious, but long-standing T-SQL tradition. Nothing much you can do about it other than never explicitly using that yourself.

Comment: I don't have to insert a date now. But I'm still having issues with getting the correct date. For now I've stuck with the highly inefficient @DateAdded smalldatetime = '18/01/2023' so that at the very least today everything will be right

Comment: try using `@DateAdded smalldatetime = '1900-01-01'` in the procedure parameters and add a line `IF (@DateAdded = '1900-01-01')  @DateAdded = GETDATE();` as a line immediately before your insert. But Sergey's comment is the better way if you are allowed to change the definition.

Comment: As per my earlier comment, I recommend using `@DateAdded SMALLDATETIME = NULL` for the parameter declaration, and then amend your `VALUES` clause to use `ISNULL(@DateAdded, GETDATE())` rather than plain `@DateAdded`. No need for special values here. As others have noted, if `@DateAdded` is never supposed to be supplied by the caller, it's a much better idea to have a default constraint take care of it and not offer it as a parameter at all.

Comment: In reference to your "today is correct" hack, you have a string literal for a date but the format is ambiguous and can be mistaken for the wrong date. You should always use the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD when using string literals for dates. It is the only format that will work every single time regardless of language and other sql server settings.

Answer (score 1):

The only things you can pass to a stored procedure are constants and variables.

Per Microsoft Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/specify-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16

`GETDATE()` is a function and functions cannot be used to pass parameter values or used as the default parameter values.  You have to remove the default value using the `GETDATE()` function.

Two possible workarounds to your problem.

1. Declare a local variable inside the stored procedure set to `GETDATE()`.  Use that local variable.
2. Create a variable set to `GETDATE()`, and pass the variable to the stored procedure.

Ex of #1 above, declaring a local variable inside the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spAddStuffExample 
--These are Passed Parameters, these cannot use functions
@Name varchar(100),
@EmailAddress varchar(100),
@ContactNumber varchar(100),
@AdditionalInformation varchar(3000) = NULL -- = NULL is a default

AS

--Declare local variable using a function
DECLARE @DateAdded smalldatetime = GETDATE();

set nocount on;

--Use passed parameters and local variable together
insert into dbo.TableName (Name, EmailAddress, ContactNumber,AdditionalInformation , DateAdded)
    values(@Name, @EmailAddress, @ContactNumber,@AdditionalInformation, @DateAdded);
```